# GnomeGmail for Google Inbox (attachments)?

Tags: mail, gmail, email-client, attachment

GnomeGmail did a nice job as default mail client sending attachments, e.g. from LibreWriter, but since I moved to Google Inbox, the Gnome Gmail only opens it, without attaching anything or opening the compose dialog box.

Is there a GnomeGoogleInbox?

Answer (score 0):

Hello here is great project for that:
https://github.com/Thomas101/wmail/releases